# Another way to avoid 1000 lines of code (declaration and an enormous Case tree)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that loop through rows of information in a table (1 row = 1 object), where it extracts 5 pieces of information where 3 of these will be used to determine belonging (its rightful place within a range of cells) and the 4th is the name. The 5th variable  determines the cell color (filling).

My first approach was a Case Statement, but it turns out that this will result in quite a big code and I'm wondering if this cannot be solved in a more sophisticated way.
Currently, my code looks as follows:

-
Is there another way of checking these conditions and then adding a name + cell color to a predetermined named range without using this massive structure (and the necessary declaration?

```
Function 1 'grabs variable 1 from the database. This can have 4 values
Function 2 'grabs variable 2 from the database. This can have 5 values
Function 3 'grabs variable 3 "kort, medel or long) from the database
Function 4 'grabs the project name or "Projektkod" from the database
Function 5 'grabs a number between 1-6 that determine "cellColor" name

Dim A1_O1K As Range '1 of 100s. Same with the counter below
Set A1_O1K = OverviewUtvecklingSheet.Range("A1_O1K")     'This will be a named range - consisting of several cells
Dim A1_O1KCounter As Integer      ' to keep track on so that 1 cell in 1 range only get populated once
A1_O1KCounter = 0

    Dim cellColor As Long
    Select Case Projektfas     
        Case 1
             cellColor = eColor(1)
        Case 2
             cellColor = eColor(2)
        Case 3
             cellColor = eColor(3)
        Case 4
             cellColor = eColor(4)
        Case 5
             cellColor = eColor(5)
        Case 6
             cellColor = eColor(6)               
    End Select



    Select Case Variable1
        Case "Variable1 A"
            Select Case Variable 2                
                Case Is = "Variable 2 A"
                    If Projektsikt = "Kort" Then
                        A1_O1KCounter = A1_O1KCounter + 1
                        A1_O1K.Cells(A1_O1KCounter) = Projektkod
                        A1_O1K.Cells(A1_O1KCounter).Interior.Color = BorderColor                                                     
                    ElseIf Projektsikt = "Medel" Then
                        A1_O1MCounter = A1_O1MCounter + 1
                        A1_O1M.Cells(A1_O1MCounter) = Projektkod
                        A1_O1M.Cells(A1_O1MCounter).Interior.Color = BorderColor                           
                    ElseIf Projektsikt = "Lång" Then
                        A1_O1LCounter = A1_O1LCounter + 1
                        A1_O1L.Cells(A1_O1LCounter) = Projektkod
                        A1_O1L.Cells(A1_O1LCounter).Interior.Color = BorderColor                          
                    End If
                Case Is = "Variable 2 B"
                    If Projektsikt = "Kort" Then                         
                    ElseIf Projektsikt = "Medel" Then                          
                    ElseIf Projektsikt = "Lång" Then                            
                    End If
                Case Is = "Variable 2 C"
                    ..
                Case Is = "Variable 2 D"
                    ..                                              
            End Select                            

     Case "Variable1 B"
            Select Case Variable 2  
                 Case Is = "Variable 2 A"
                    If Projektsikt = "Kort" Then                   
                    ElseIf Projektsikt = "Medel" Then                   
                    ElseIf Projektsikt = "Lång" Then
                    End If
                Case Is = "Variable 2 B"
                Case Is = "Variable 2 C"
                Case Is = "Variable 2 D"
            End select


       Case "Variable1 C"
       Case "Variable1 D"


       End Select
    End Select


Next
```

'The following is all my declaration for just 1 row (Area 1 in the image).

```
Public A1_O1K As Range
Public A1_O1M As Range
Public A1_O1L As Range
Public A1_O1KCounter As Integer
Public A1_O1MCounter As Integer
Public A1_O1LCounter As Integer                                                                   
Set A1_O1K = OverviewUtvecklingSheet.Range("A1_O1K")
Set A1_O1M = OverviewUtvecklingSheet.Range("A1_O1M")
Set A1_O1L = OverviewUtvecklingSheet.Range("A1_O1L")
A1_O1KCounter = 0
A1_O1MCounter = 0
A1_O1LCounter = 0
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you gave some specific examples (not code, but words). How many cases for each variable? The issue isn't exactly clear. It may help to create arrays to loop through?

Comment: Whatever the variable `Projektfas` is it seems to be almost an Index for `eColor` so instead of a `Select Case` statement why not just `cellColor = eColor(Projektfas)`?

Comment: Lookup tables and VLookup

Comment: Maybe it would help if you **show** specific examples (not code, not words, but DATA) of current input and desired output. Also, I see *database* used. Advise if data originates in an actual database or inside Excel.

Comment: @urdearboy, of course - my apologies. So it's a hierarchy where the first one is "on-top" of the second one and so on. The 1st variable have 4 cases, the 2nd one have 5 cases, and the 3rd one have 3 cases. The issue is the many lines. I will have about 200 named ranges (down from 800 luckily). Each of these are declared once and assigned a value, also I provide each with a counter to ensure that a cell only get populated once. So this is 4 lines per named range = 800 lines of code for just the declaration!... The array thing is interesting, I'm not quite sure how you would go about that tho?

Comment: @Tom, that is a great addition. I'll for sure change that. Thank you!

Comment: @Parfait, my apologies. The database is just in another excel sheet -  in the same workbook. Also, please see the image below. I hope this explains it. So first you have "Function" which is my "variable 1" - 4 different functions/input data are possible.  Secondly, "Area" or my "variable 2" - can have 4 different values. Third, you see "short" in the upper right bar. This value can be either "short", "medium", or "Long" and determines it's horizontal location. 2 other columns are therefore visible to the right. Lastly based on another variable "project phase" (1-6) a cell filling is assigned

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OMKb7sx . With the picture in mind, the input data was "Function 1", "Area 1", "Short", "K", "2". The "2" being the project phase which determines the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways this could be improved. For starters, this replaces the whole first `Select` block:

```
Dim cellColor As Long
cellColor = eColor(Projektfas)
```

For that (presumably) huge nested `Select` block I would suggest you create a separate `Sub` for each level below the first so you don't have to repeat that entire code everytime. For example (using public variables fo `A1_O1KCounter` etc.):

```
Sub Subprocedure(Projektsikt As String)

If Projektsikt = "Kort" Then
    A1_O1KCounter = A1_O1KCounter + 1
    A1_O1K.Cells(A1_O1KCounter) = Projektkod
    A1_O1K.Cells(A1_O1KCounter).Interior.Color = BorderColor
ElseIf Projektsikt = "Medel" Then
    A1_O1MCounter = A1_O1MCounter + 1
    A1_O1M.Cells(A1_O1MCounter) = Projektkod
    A1_O1M.Cells(A1_O1MCounter).Interior.Color = BorderColor
ElseIf Projektsikt = "Lång" Then
    A1_O1LCounter = A1_O1LCounter + 1
    A1_O1L.Cells(A1_O1LCounter) = Projektkod
    A1_O1L.Cells(A1_O1LCounter).Interior.Color = BorderColor
End If

End Sub
```

This procedure can be called everytime you need this particular check to happen. `Call Subprocedure(Projektsikt)`

In general, every repetitive piece of code can be "outsourced" to a different procedure to avoid redundancies. Without knowing the entire architecture of your code I presume there is also some potential for optimization when setting up the variables and the general structure.

Comment: thank you so much! This will save me so much time - incredibly smooth. The second (case statement for another purpose) would have been about 3 times the size of this one haha, ridiculous! Any chance I also could bother you with the declaration part as well? Like, would you write 800 lines (1 range declaration, 1 assigning the range, 1 counter, giving the counter value of 0) for my about 200 named ranges? For this purpose, each named range will consist of 4 predetermined cells (to be filled if certain conditions are fulfilled)

Comment: I'd be glad to help, but I might need to know a bit more about your specific case and will be out of office tommorrow. I would need a code sample of how you would do it, including maybe 2 or 3 of your named ranges. I need to see how they differ from each other etc. I will get back to you on Friday at the latest!

Comment: of course - whenever you have time. I truly appreciate the help! Perhaps this image can shed some light on the intended output https://imgur.com/a/OMKb7sx . It i all about populating the right cells in that "table". The first column "Function" have 4 different values. The second column "Area" have 4 different values per "Function". In total, this sums up to 16 potential values for "Area". Counting from above, "Area 1" can be the same as "Area 10" - meaning the same area can exist in multiple "Functions". Lastly, each project is either "short", "medium", or "long"

Comment: Under each of these (short, medium, long), 16 cells exist to be populated one at a time if certain conditions are fulfilled. In addition, based on an index value from one of the functions mentioned in the Q description, the cell is also to be "colored"

Comment: Please check the Q description (the code part) - I will add a part of my declaration.

Comment: Edit: The naming is not important (the ranges)

Comment: I looked at everything you provided but still do not have a grasp of what you're trying to do. Would you be able to provide a sample workbook with let`s say four of your named ranges along with a sample of your desired output?

Comment: Could you just share a file? If not, pictures would be best I think.

Comment: so-throwaway@web.de